# Recommandations for cluster's nodes resources on Hadoop ?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, administration

Is it recommended to use the same ressources (CPU and RAM) on all machines of a cluster  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infrastructure configuration of your cluster would be determined by the business case for which you are building the cluster which would in turn translate to data processing requirement that cluster needs to meet to achieve the business outcome. In General, hadoop system were initially designed with the notion there would be machines with heterogeneous configuration in a cluster. (Now Server vendors have machines optimized for hadoop workload , with some disk sizing variability between  Masters and Slaves ).

To address your questions specifically , i have seen at some sites cluster with up to 50 nodes with exact same configuration for masters and slaves (which i thought was a bit of an over kill). Quiet often architectural design decisions do not always determine procurement decisions.

The following links from 3 major Hadoop Distribution providers would be a good starting point to understand more on cluster design and apply  site specific parameters (i.e. Data processing needs,data growth,data retention,replication..etc ):

Hortonworks:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.5/bk_cluster-planning/bk_cluster-planning.pdf

Cloudera:

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-select-the-right-hardware-for-your-new-hadoop-cluster/

MAPR:

http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Planning+Cluster+Hardware

Comment: Thank you @Kfactor21 for your interesting answer. We have some problems in job's processing on Yarn ( from time to another, a job stop all the excusion of applications on Yarn) , and we think that is caused by the differences in ressources which are from some nodes to anothers.
Also we use the RM and NM on the same machine, do you think that coud be the reason of this issue since the jobs concerned were running in this node ?

Comment: Hi @AymanAnikad , I would advise you to open a new question with the issue you are facing.You have a better chance of getting help from the community. Without information about your cluster its difficult to say what the issue could be. 

Please provide atleast the following in your question:
Environment details (Hadoop Distribution,Infrastructure details (MasterNodes/Datanodes and respective CPU/RAM/DISK details) /YARN memory configurations, container sizes,Name Node Heap size), HDFS Block size. Job logs from resource manager ,YARN log, atleast sections around the error .

Comment: It's ok . I will do that.  Thank you for your recommandations :)